# Floating label in input field with supported all browsers, without js and without required attribute

Tags: html, css

I have created floating label in input field.In chrome view is working fine, but not properly viewed in mozilla firefox, please anyone help me, how to write code,
note: Kindly suggest without javascript and without required attribute in input field.

My code is attached

```css
.has-float-label
{
    position:relative
}
.has-float-label label
{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;top:0;
    cursor:text;
    font-size:75%;
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition:all .2s;
    transition:all .2s
}
.has-float-label select
{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none
}
.has-float-label .form-control
{
    font-size:inherit;
    padding-top:1em;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border:0;
    border-radius:0;
    background:0 0;
    border-bottom:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
    opacity:1;
    -webkit-transition:all .2s;
    transition:all .2s
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-moz-input-placeholder
{
    opacity:1;
    -moz-transition:all .2s;
    transition:all .2s
}

.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder
{
    opacity:0
}

.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-moz-input-placeholder
{
    opacity:0
}

.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)+label
{
    font-size:150%;
    opacity:.5;
    top:.25em
}
.has-float-label .form-control:focus
{
    outline:0;
    border-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5)
}
.input-group .has-float-label
{
    display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group has-float-label">
    <input class="form-control" id="first" type="text" placeholder="First Last"/>
    <label for="first">Name</label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we remove all the styles that corresponds to `select` css selector from the code, as we don't need it. The selectors `.has-float-label`, `.has-float-label label` and `.has-float-label .form-control` remained untouched as it does not relate with what you are trying to accomplish.

To the main part now.

```
.has-float-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder
.has-float-label .form-control::-moz-placeholder
.has-float-label .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder
.has-float-label .form-control::placeholder
```

The `::placeholder` pseudo-element (a visible thing that isn't really in the DOM) allow us to style the placeholder text (it wraps the actual placeholder text). In this case we add the `transition` property to make a smooth transition when the user clicks on the input.

We use the platform-native selectors (`-webkit-` for Safari and Chrome, `-moz-` for Firefox, `-ms-` for Internet Explorer) to make our code more standards-compliant.

*The `::placeholder` selector is not part of the main CSS standards.* *We also added the `-webkit-` platform-native selectors for the same reasons.*

```
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-moz-placeholder
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::placeholder
```

The above selectors are quite interesting. Let's break them to pieces:

`placeholder-shown` pseudo-class selects the `<input>` when placeholder text is shown.

`not(:focus)` is a CSS3 selector matches every element that is NOT `:focus`. This allow us to hide the placeholder text and show only the label when the cursor is not inside the `input` element.

`placeholder` again is used for the same reason as we described. The `opacity` property with zero value allow us to hide the placeholder text.

Lastly, `.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus) + *` will make the label transition to the top.

```css
.has-float-label {
  position: relative;
}
.has-float-label label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 75%;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}

.has-float-label .form-control {
font-size:inherit;
    padding-top:1em;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    border:0;
    border-radius:0;
    background:0 0;
    border-bottom:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1)
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control::-moz-placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:-ms-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control::placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::-moz-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus):-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus) + * {
  font-size: 150%;
  opacity: .5;
  top: .25em;
}
.has-float-label .form-control:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group has-float-label">
    <input class="form-control" id="first" type="text" placeholder="First Last"/>
    <label for="first">Name</label>
  </div>
```

**Note:** The above code does not work with Edge. To make it work change the following:

```
/* Remove this */
/* has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus)::placeholder {
 *   opacity: 0;
 * }
 */
/* Add the following lines */

.has-float-label .form-control:not(:focus)::-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. As it stand now it reads as a spot-the-difference game

Comment: @j08691 I'll do, please give me some moments.

Comment: @JonesJoseph is this the only broswer that fails?

Comment: @GeorgeGkasdrogkas yep i think so...
 i checked chrome, opera, firefox and edge.

Comment: @JonesJoseph check the mobile as well. let me try to find a solution if possible. If you'd like, accept my answer and like it as well.

Comment: I have found the solution... the edit queue was full i will post it as a comment.. i removed the `placeholder-shown` for `-ms-input-placeholder` element and it worked in edge. also i added a version of it with double colon `::`

Comment: @JonesJoseph I didn't understand what your removed.

Comment: @GeorgeGkasdrogkas check this fiddle to know what i modified https://jsfiddle.net/zfpo5gcr/2/

Comment: @GeorgeGkasdrogkas Add a version without `placeholder-shown` for this line too `.has-float-label .form-control:placeholder-shown:not(:focus) + *` ?

Comment: @JonesJoseph can you edit my answer? Write the appropriate fixes there.

Comment: @GeorgeGkasdrogkas Done !! `:)`